# SQL Server TSQL conventions/patterns on SET, WITH and ENABLE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, design-patterns

After years of using TSQL, I still cannot figure out when to use `SET`, `WITH` or `ENABLE`.

When you read TSQL statement like,

```
ALTER TABLE Person.Person
ENABLE CHANGE_TRACKING 
WITH (TRACK_COLUMNS_UPDATED = ON);
```

It looks more intuitive and readable if it was written like (invalid query below),

```
ALTER TABLE Person.Person
SET CHANGE_TRACKING = ON,
    TRACK_COLUMNS_UPDATED = ON
```

I am always getting confused between when to use `SET`, `ENABLE`, or `WITH` options

When are those options being used in TSQL?
Is TSQL just being inconsistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SET is only ever used:

1. As a standalone statement to modify a variables value, or..
2. .. to modify certain connection settings.
3. Or, as a clause of the DML statement, UPDATE.

ENABLE is only ever a Clause of DDL or DAL statements

WITH is always a dependent clause of other statements (though this is confusing for CTE's where it is a prefixing dependent clause)

So, SET should be clear, however, admittedly there does not seem to be any consistent rule about WITH vs ENABLE.

Comment: @RBarry: Thanks, I am actually not seeing any consistency in SQL server naming.  I guess this is something I just suck it up and memorize...  It's just annoying that I just spotted "ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorksLT     SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON;" where the statement uses the verb "ALLOW" in the option instead of "enable"...  This is just getting out of hand..